# Expression Syntax error in TurboC++

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I want to compile and run this in TurboC++, I am getting Expression Syntax error at line
else if(text[i]==' '))

I have also tried in codeblocks with minor changes but it returned "counting - Debug" uses an invalid compiler. Probably the toolchain path within the compiler options is not setup correctly?! Skipping...
Nothing to be done.

Anyways my main aim is to make it run in turboc++

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h> 

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int nu,nl,nd,nb,ns;
    char text[100];
    nu=nl=nd=nb=ns=0;
    cout<<"enter a line of text\n";
    cin>>text;
    for(int i=0;text[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
    if(isupper(text[i]))
        nu++;
    else if(islower(text[i]))
        nl++;
    else if(isdigit(text[i]))
        nd++;
    else if(text[i]==' '))
        nb++;
    else
    ns++;
    cout<<"total number of uppercase alphabets="<< nu << ".\n";
    cout<<"total number of lowercase alphabets="<< nl << ".\n";
    cout<<"total number of digits="<< nd << ".\n";
    cout<<"total number of blank spaces="<< nb << ".\n";
    cout<<"total number of other symbols="<< ns << ".\n";
    getch();
}
```

Comment: I would recommend brushing up on how to format your code, and it would also be helpful for you to use an IDE that will easily match opening/closing braces/parens/etc.

Comment: ya that was a silly mistake, but why am I getting the answers wrong when I enter text with numbers and letters...

Comment: now compiled and runs..!!!

but I am not getting correct answers....its just giving lowercase alphabets 1 no matter whatever i types....
and when i press enter it doesnt close the window but again gives out repeadtedly.

Comment: _'but why am I getting the answers wrong when I enter text with numbers and letters...'_ Edit either this question, or even better ask a new one for this.

Comment: An expression syntax error is what it is, an expression syntax error. Check your syntax

Comment: I have reverted your question back to the original one. It is not a good idea to completely change the meaning of your question when an answer has already been posted solving it. It makes the post unreadable because the answer no longer matches the question. Instead, post the new problem as a new question.

Comment: TurboC++ is over nearly 24 years old, not standards compliant by any stretch and is inadequate for learning C++. Consider updating to a newer compiler unless you have to use it for school in which case you should request a refund.

Comment: I wanted to run it in TurboC++ itself since I need to show it run to a student from school where they use turboc++ only...

Comment: having nowadays good compilers for free, and good IDE too, what's the point for a school in using such a dinosaur like TurboC++?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious What are you talking about, 24 years? You're exaggerating! I remember buying "Learn TurboC++" software when I was in school, and that was only 21 years ago, 22 tops!  ...no, wait...I bought it used.

Answer (score 4):

```
else if(text[i]==' '))
```

You have one extra closing parenthesis here

Comment: Just now only i fixed that...

Answer (score 0):

Well I have found solution to all the problems of the wrong answer being coming repeatedly and other code mistakes..here is the final code..!!

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void main()

{
//clrscr();
int nu,nl,nd,nb,ns;
char text[100];
    nu=nl=nd=nb=ns=0;
    cout<<"Enter a line of text.\n";
    gets(text);
    for(int i=0;text[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(isupper(text[i]))
            nu++;
        else if(islower(text[i]))
            nl++;
        else if(isdigit(text[i]))
            nd++;
        else if(text[i]==' ')
            nb++;
        else
            ns++;
}
cout<<"total number of uppercase alphabets="<<nu<< ".\n";
cout<<"total number of lowercase alphabets="<<nl<< ".\n";
cout<<"total number of digits="<<nd<< ".\n";
cout<<"total number of blank spaces="<<nb<< ".\n";
cout<<"total number of other symbols="<<ns<< ".\n";
getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is missing a closing curly brace.